# Loading Multiple Images from Url Causing Memory warnings and crashes app when scrolling

Tags: image, memory-management, uicollectionview

I am using SdWebImage to load images asynchronously,

First I used Scrollview and image view To load the images caused memory warning.

Then I shifted Collection view, still got memory issue. Now I want to release the memory of offscreen image views which will reduce the memory usage.

```
 -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      CustomCollectionCell *cell = (CustomCollectionCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      [cell.Imgview sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[[self.Actualimagearray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]objectForKey:@"FilePath"]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"loader.png"]];
      return cell;
}

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

      CustomCollectionCell *customcell=(CustomCollectionCell *)cell;
      customcell.Imgview=nil;

}
```

So after the use of didEnddisplay cell, Im not getting any memory issue, But My Images are r getting altered as On scrolling (2nd image comes into 1st and 3rd image comes in to 2nd etc..).

So what is the better way to release the memory of UnseenImages?